# ms-access insert query error

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbconnection, insert-statement

I am trying to savedata in access data base but getting error "Exception : Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. "

```
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO UserDetails (Username,Email,Password) VALUES (@username,@email,@password)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", RegisterUsernameText.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", EmailTextbox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", PasswordReapettextbox.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Password is a reserved keyword. Put it between square brackets as [Password] or better change that column name

Comment: It looks like you`re saving a plain text password.  You might want to look into saving a hash instead to be safe.

Comment: Thanks guys.. it worked for me with '[Password]' in insert statement